# How to replace a pattern matched by regex in a list with a list of tuples?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.5

I have a text file, which I have processed as strings in a list of lines which match a certain pattern. I want to replace the matched part of the line with a tuple that I have in a list

```
 D= ['M2 (net23 Vin\\- net20 0) nmos1',
     'M1 (net19 Vin\\+ net20 0) nmos1', 
     'M7 (vout\\- net29 0 0) nmos1',
     'M5 (net20 net29 0 0) nmos1' ,
     'NM4 (net29 net29 0 0) nmos1',
     'NM3 (net22 net29 0 0) nmos1' ]
```

and I have written a process which generates

```
k = [('breach', 'Vin\\-', 'net20', '0'),
     ('net19', 'Vin\\+', 'net20', '0'),
     ('vout\\-', 'net29', '0', '0'),
     ('net20', 'net29', '0', '0'),
     ('net29', 'net29', '0', '0'),
     ('net22', 'net29', '0', '0')]
```

I need the output to be

```
['M2 (breach Vin\\- net20 0) nmos1',
 'M1 (net19 Vin\\+ net20 0) nmos1', 
 'M7 (vout\\- net29 0 0) nmos1',
 'M5 (net20 net29 0 0) nmos1',
 'NM4 (net29 net29 0 0) nmos1',
 'NM3 (net22 net29 0 0) nmos1' ]
```

I could do this manually, but I want to do this for all the nodes inside, one at a time.

I have tried

```
cmos_regex_pattern = re.compile('(.*) (\(.*\)) (nmos1|pmos1) ((.*))')
for line in D:
   data = cmos_regex_pattern.search(line)
   if data:
       re.sub(cmos_regex_pattern,str(k),data.group(2))
```

So far, but it does not do anything.

another thing, i tired is

```
    regex_pattern = re.compile('(.*) (\(.*\)) (nmos1|pmos1) ((.*))')
    for i in range(len(D)):
         find = D[i]
         #print(find)
         replace = k[i]
         #print(replace)
         for line in D:
         print (line)
         new_line = regex_pattern.sub(find,replace,line)
```

but it comes up with an error 
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer at location newline.

Comment: What show as being in `Total_Mos_device` isn't valid Python syntax, Please [edit] yor question and fix this. We need to see a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in my example. I have changed it to a minimally reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

To your first try:

- If you have a look at `str(k)` in the debugger, you will see that this is not a single line of `k`, but rather a string representation of the whole array, see [str](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-str).
- In the regex, only match the part of the text you want to replace, see [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html?highlight=re%20sub#re.sub).

To your second try:

- You are passing a tuple as replace, which is expected to be a string or a function instead (see [join](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) in the example below).

The following example uses [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) for iterating through `D`/`k` combinations. You might need to adapt this if your data is less uniform than in the shown samples.

```
result = []
cmos_regex_pattern = re.compile('(\(.*\))') # the pattern that matches the text which should be replaced
for k_data, line in zip(k, D):
    k_str = "(" + " ".join(k_data) + ")" # the text which replaces the matched text
    result.append(re.sub(cmos_regex_pattern, k_str, line)) # perform the replacement in the current line, and add the result to the 'result' array
```